# JMS queue : selective listener

Tags: architecture, jms, message-queue

Assume a jboss cluster with 5 nodes. Typically you will have a deployable unit where you will listen to a JMS queue and when deployed to all nodes in the cluster each node will have the listener up and running.

My use case is, architecturally, what can I do so that only 3 out of 5 nodes will have listeners to the queue ?

One solution I can think of is to have Master/slave architecture where the master tells which nodes to have the listener up.

Comment: I should add that the above scenario is one 1 environment, say PROD

Answer (score 0):

This is normally done via some environmental configuration (classically JNDI).  This allows each environment to be independent, but still allow you to configure per-instance behavior.